# Spread syntax in front of brackets?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading info about [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) from MDN and I have stumbled upon the following example that left me a bit cold, despite going over the material progressively.

The code giving me trouble is this:

```
function myFunction(v, w, x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1];
myFunction(-1, ...args, 2, ...[3]);
```

I get that `v==-1`; `w==0`; `x==1`; and `y==2`... but what is **`...[3]`**?

The example is from the spread syntax hyperlink above.

Comment: It's just an array literal. Think `var args2 = [3];` and `...args2`.

Comment: thanks I panicked and posted question a bit prematurely. One positive thing is that I learned that you can copy arrays without slice that way: var arr = [1,2,3]; var arr2 = [...arr]; // like arr.slice()

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: @FelixKling first of all ty for ur contributions to the community. many of us dont have a cs background and is amazing to have someone with ur willingness to share top-notch knowledge :) So u would describe it as an element? (because it clearly seems to conduct an operation).

Comment: `...` doesn't really have a name. It's a punctuator that is only meaningful in context. Take `;` for example. It's meaning is different in `for( ; ; ) {}` and `var x=42;`. Same with `...`, although the different occurrences are closer related. In your example, since the context is a function *call* you can refer to `...arg` as a *spread argument*. It's not an operator because an operator produces a single value and can be embedded into other expression. However you cannot do `42 + ...someValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you've found is a bit contrived, and you probably wouldn't see it in real code. It's just meant to illustrate that the spread argument syntax `...` works with any iterable expression, including standard array literals like `[1, 2, 3]`. `z` will be `3` because

```
myFunction(-1, ...args, 2, ...[3]);
```

is equivalent to

```
myFunction(-1, ...args, 2, 3);
```

The `...[` and `]` essentially have no effect in this case; the values are pulled out of the array so it's as though you'd just written them directly in the argument list. As another example,

```
myFunction(-1, ...args, 2, ...[3, 4, 5]);
```

is equivalent to

```
myFunction(-1, ...args, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

although `z` would still be `3` (`4` and `5` would be ignored because they're unexpected extra arguments).

Let's break this down a bit: the behaviour of the spread/rest syntax `...` in an argument list is defined in [section 12.3.6.1 "Runtime Semantics: ArgumentListEvaluation"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-argument-lists-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation) of ECMAScript 6. To paraphrase, it essentially says "when you see `...X` in an argument list, evaluate `X`, then go through the values it contains and add each of them as a separate argument".

So, when JavaScript sees `, 3` in an argument list, it says "add `3` to the argument list".

But when JavaScript sees `, ...[3]` in an argument list, it says "create a new array containing `3`, then go through each of its values (only `3`) and add them to the argument list".

You're doing the same thing in both cases, but the simpler way is probably faster.

Comment: So is it like spreading [3] in its contents, that is 3 itself? So if it was ...[3,4]; it would be 3,4?

Comment: @alexandros84 Yes, that's right, and that is a good further example to add to my answer. Yes, it's as though the `...[` and `]` aren't there; any values you put inside the brackets will be treated as arguments the same as if they were outside.

Comment: This is a great way indeed to copy arrays, var arr = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [...arr]; // like arr.slice()

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)